# Why i am unable to see my literal control on generating a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a piece of code where I generate a report and also produce an output file in `.txt` format under same button. But I am unable to see my literal control, why is it happening?

This is my sample code:

```
xmlpath = Server.MapPath("~/WebClientXslt/");
string newxslt = "941Report";
string x = Server.MapPath("~/WebClientXslt/" + newxslt + ".xsl");
string y = (xmlpath + "Testdo.xml");
USAReport.XmlTransformation xmltran = new USAReport.XmlTransformation();
xmltran.Transform(y, x);
//  XsltArgumentList XSLTArgs;
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
XslCompiledTransform xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
XslTrans.Load(x);
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(y);
returnhtml = ConvertXML(xDoc, x, new XsltArgumentList());
//Response.Write(returnhtml);
ltReport.Visible = true;
ltReport.Text = returnhtml;
```

After this I wrote a bit of code to generate a txt file to user, like this:

```
oCPyResults.generate941();
```

Where I write my code as follows in that function:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + "");
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/text";
HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(strPath);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

After the above code executes I am unable to see my report in literal control on my form which was generated what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you are trying to do on a single page. You are trying to tell the browser that the page it's loading is both a file that should be downloaded AND also a separate set of content that should be displayed as normal. It can only do one of these, which is why you get the either/or behavior when you comment/uncomment the Response.End line.

Any solution to your problem will involve TWO requests: one for the page that will be displayed, and one to prompt the Save As dialog for downloading the txt file.

Here's one possible way of making it SEEM like it's doing what you want:

1. Make your code respond to to a querystring variable that tells it whether to output to the Literal, or to run the code in your `generate941()` method.
2. Display the normal page (output to the Literal), but include a hidden iframe on your page that will point to the same page with the querystring variable that will force the download.

Something like:

```
<iframe src="/myreportpage.aspx?download=y" style="display:none" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

See what happens if you take the line out:  `HttpContext.Current.Response.End();`

if You call Response.End before the render stage of the page lifecycle, it won't render any of your content.

Comment: Still the same issue if i un comment that function i am able to see the literal control with my report but with that code executing i am unable to see the report

Comment: At the moment you basically want to return 2 responses, 1 to display the report and 2 to download the file. This will not work unfortunately as you can only return 1 response per request. The best way would be to fire a second request once the client side code is loaded that will download the file